# Application turned yellow in Mule management console

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component, mule-module-jpa

I deployed 5 applications to my Mule server in mule management console. Among the 5 application one application status was suddenly changed into yellow remaining 4 application where in green status and running successfully.

I redeployed that particular application was turned into yellow but it doesn't change into green. So I restarted the server once, after that I couldn't find that application under "Server" tab which was shown in yellow status. I also can't find the application in server folder under $MULE_HOME/apps directory.

Is it possible for me to bring back the application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the yellow status is some dependency file/function was missing in that particular application.

Currently, I couldn't find a solution to bring back the deleted application in server/MMC hence I redeployed the application in server once again.